# Best way to serve web services for an existing c# project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services

What is the best way to integrate webservices to an existing C# 4 project to serve data provided by this application ?

These webservices need to be accessible by different types of client like PHP and access need to be secured.

I started investigations with WCF but it seems to be very complex for small things...
Is there any frameworks easier to implement that ?

Comment: WCF is very easy for small things; there's just some terminology to learn. Create yourself a new "WCF Service Application" project and look at how simple the code is, especially in .NET 4.0.

Comment: For a specific answer you need to be specific. What data format(s) for the PHP? What is the existing app? etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with John that WCF can be easy for small things.  You may want to consider using [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106) if you have an existing data context (Linq2SQL or Entity Framework) - this makes it pretty easy to serve up your data and also create custom service methods to perform specific actions.

I can provide more specific answers if you elaborate in your question what you're looking to do.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your Finally, you're right, WCF was the easiest way to make what i want.